# scipy.io and numpy : type(element.item(0)) vs element.item(0).dtype.type?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

What is the difference between `type(element.item(0))` and `element.item(0).dtype.type`?

For example, the following prints :

```
print(type(element.item(0)))
print(element.item(0).dtype.type)
```

give :

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.void'>
```

I would expecting it would give the same datatype.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the `shape` and `dtype` of `element?  How about `element.item(0)` - shape and dtype.  `type` doesn't help much when exploring the nesting of arrays produced by `io.loadmat`.  This can be complex if the MATLAB source is `cell` and `struct`.

Comment: My guess is that `element` is an object dtype array containing array(s).  That first array is a structured array with a compound dtype (i.e. multiple fields).  In MATLAB that might have been a cell of struct, or struct matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at some simple known arrays.

2d integer:

```
In [221]: x
Out[221]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [222]: x.dtype
Out[222]: dtype('int64')
In [223]: x.dtype.type
Out[223]: numpy.int64
In [224]: type(x[0])
Out[224]: numpy.ndarray
In [225]: type(x.item(0))
Out[225]: int
```

Converted to object dtype:

```
In [226]: y = x.astype(object)
In [227]: y
Out[227]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
In [228]: y.dtype
Out[228]: dtype('O')
In [229]: y.dtype.type
Out[229]: numpy.object_
In [230]: type(y[0])
Out[230]: numpy.ndarray
In [231]: type(y.item(0))
Out[231]: int
```

Array of arrays:

```
In [232]: z = np.array([np.arange(3), np.arange(2)],object)
In [233]: z
Out[233]: array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1])], dtype=object)
In [234]: z.dtype
Out[234]: dtype('O')
In [235]: z.item(0)
Out[235]: array([0, 1, 2])    # clearly ndarray type
In [236]: z[0]
Out[236]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

structured array:

```
In [237]: w = np.zeros(2, 'i,f')
In [238]: w
Out[238]: array([(0, 0.), (0, 0.)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
In [239]: w.dtype
Out[239]: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
In [240]: w.dtype.type
Out[240]: numpy.void         # compound dtype
In [241]: w[0]
Out[241]: (0, 0.)
In [242]: type(_)
Out[242]: numpy.void
In [243]: w.item(0)
Out[243]: (0, 0.0)
In [244]: type(_)
Out[244]: tuple
```

`dtype.type` and `type(item)`, while not un-related, don't tell us the same thing.  I'd focus on `dtype` and `shape`, and only if those aren't useful look at `type`.  I'd even risk a:

```
data = io.loadmat(...)
print(data)
```

it may display a lot, though `numpy` summarizes large array.